# Firebase Database not updating in flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a chatting app. I have done all the processes to install firebase and my app is working fine. But when I connected the firebase database and tried to store the messages into the database. The database does not update with the new document(message and user email).

This is my code -

this is how my firebase database page looks like
[image]

this is how my app looks like
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flash_chat/constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'chat_screen';

  @override _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final _firestore = Firestore.instance;
  String messageText;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedinUser;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedinUser = user;
        print(user.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: null,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                _auth.signOut();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                //Implement logout functionality
              }),
        ],
        title: Text('⚡️Chat'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              decoration: kMessageContainerDecoration,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: TextField(
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        messageText = value;
                        //Do something with the user input.
                      },
                      decoration: kMessageTextFieldDecoration,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _firestore.collection('messages').add({
                        'sender': loggedinUser.email,
                        'text': messageText,
                      });
                      //Implement send functionality.
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**

Comment: Do you have sufficient permissions? Do you see any error message?

Comment: Yes, I have all the permissions and I don't see any error images.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is you're trying to add data with `null` values, and that's why you don't see any changes.

The values that seems to be `null` are `loggedinUser.email` and `messageText`, check if the user has an `email` and for the `messageText`, in `onChanged` you should do `messageText = value;` inside a `setState()`, but instead of doing that you could add a `controller` to the `TextField` and then use `controller.text`.